# Web Audio API with Chrome 26.0.1410.64 m

Tags: web-audio-api

I have used Web Audio API followed the tutorial on HTML5 Rock. I have added one audio context with 11 tracks of mp3 files, each file plays about 5 min.

This app works perfectly fine before I accidentally update my chrome to 26.0.1410.64m (PC version). In this new version of chrome, this app crash everytime with no exception.

However,the app can work fine in the latest MAC version of chrome. And if I load smaller mp3 files (5 track that each play for 1min) to latest version of PC chrome, nothing goes wrong. I have tried to fully uninstall the latest version in my win8 PC and install early version of chrome, the problem still exists.

Anyone has any idea about this problem? It really freaks me out.

Comment: Can update your question with some code? How are you playing/loading the mp3s?